# F# and AzureStorage GetBlobContainer

Tags: f#, azure-storage

Has anyone  used the WindowsAzure.Storage NuGet package in a F# project?  I am trying to upload a photo to Azure storage using this code:

```
member this.InsertPhotoImage(photoImage: PhotoImage) =
    let storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString)
    let blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
    let container = this.GetBlobContainer(blobClient) 
    let photoUri = this.GetPhotoImageUri(photoImage.UniqueId)
    let blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(photoUri) 
    use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(photoImage.ImageBytes)
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream)
```

and I am getting this exception on the container.GetBlockBlobReference and blockBlob.UploadFromStream lines:
*Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point.*

When I do an explicit cast like this on this line

```
    let container = this.GetBlobContainer(blobClient) :> CloudBlobContainer
```

It compiles but I get this warning:

*The type 'CloudBlobContainer' does not have any proper subtypes and need not be used as the target of a static coercion*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it is a problem with me and the step-down rule

I need to create the helper functions (in this case GetBlobContainer) BEFORE using them.